# Detect current navigation bar title font name and size?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if there is a way to detect the current font and size used by iOS for the title shown in the navigation bar.

Is it possible to detect what Font (name and size) it's been used by the system?

Comment: Do you need to check it at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in detecting it at runtime to make sure I know what it is depending on the device is running on etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can run through all subviews of the navigation bar and find displayed labels, then you can get the font.

Comment: I think I can try this, I thought about it, but, I was wondering if there was a way to detect the font without having to loop through subviews....

Comment: Nope. There is no other way. Actually, you should not do that. Any reason you need to know it?

Comment: If you are using Large Titles, then you can use dynamic system font for the title, it's the same.